# How to remove Google Apps search history?

Tags: google, privacy, google-workspace

As of March 1st a lot of people seem to be jumping ship from Google due to their [new privacy policy](http://www.google.com/policies/). EFF has posted a neat little guide to how one might [opt to remove their search history](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/02/how-remove-your-google-search-history-googles-new-privacy-policy-takes-effect), but this simple guide doesn't seem to apply for Google Apps domains.

How does one view/archive/remove their Google Apps history?

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](http://www.r00tb0x.com/content/disable-browsing-history-google-apps):

1. Visit the following URL: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/[yourdomain.com]
2. Click on 'Organisation & Users' and then the 'Services' tab
3. Find the Web History service and turn it off